# tflite.allocate_tensors() fails after changing input size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use a tflite model to do inference on a batch. I use the following code:

```py
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]["index"], [batch_size, 513, 513, 3])
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

The code crashes and gives the following error:

```py
RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:58 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1579014 != 789507)Node number 0 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
```

When looking at the output details, it still has the shape `[1, 513, 513, output_channels]` and not `[batch_size, 513, 513, output_channels]` as I would hope.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Looks like the problem isn't in resize_tensor_input. You always may check if resize_tensor_input does its work by looking in interpreter.get_input_details(). Or there is a typo in your post and you meant input details in the last sentence?

Comment: Hi,do you fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a known bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16216
but there is no patches at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue and searched a lot about this. As a solution to this as recommended on tensorflow github link I used tf-nightly package and it work perfectly.
To install -

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

Once tensorflow is installed with the above step you can follow the steps below:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import interpreter
model = Interpreter(model_path='cls_prob.tflite')
input_details = model.get_input_details()
req_input_size = (2, 128, 200, 1) #Your input size
model.resize_tensor_input(input_details[0]['index'], req_input_size)
model.allocate_tensors()
```